# SharePoint list validation formula based on created and modified dates no longer evaluates as FALSE ever

Tags: validation, formula

To clarify, the formula below is for list validation and not field validation:

```
=IF(OR(NOW()<[Created]+(1/1440),NOW()<=[Modified]+(10/86400)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This checks for the following conditions:

1. Is the current date/time less than 1 minute from the created date/time
2. Is the current date/time less or equal to 10 seconds from the modified date/time
3. If either are true, it returns true.
4. Otherwise, it should return false and show an error message.

This formula used to work; however, for the last 2 weeks, it has stopped working and I don't know why as the syntax seems fine to me.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Scott

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or On-prem?